# how to connect oracle cloud database from sqlplus

Tags: c, oracle, cloud, oracle-apex, sqlplus

I am trying to connect my oracle cloud database using sqlplus with below commands.

```
sqlplus Username/Mypassword@//*************************************************
```

nothing worked . Any idea please .?

Comment: If your question is about SQL\*Plus, as it obviously is, why do you have the `oracle-sqldeveloper` tag under it? You can control the tags, both when you first write your post and later by editing the tags - even if Stack Overflow added that tag by default, it takes only one second to remove it. Also, I can't tell, but does your question have anything to do with ApEx?

Comment: What happens when you try? Also, everyone on the internet knows where your database is, and what it's called - I hope your passwords are incredibly secure

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here? https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-preparing.html#GUID-6F118C83-5BD2-4C10-88F2-B7A6280D1EE1

Comment: Yes i followed the instruction and i get below error.

ERROR:
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

Comment: well, is it an autonomous DB, or just a VMDB, or ....?

Comment: Yes it is an autonomous db.

Comment: Try SQLcl, it's easier to get connected than sqlplus..that error though sounds like a server issue not a client one. What version oracle client did you install?